# Use Regular Expression to count punctuation from user input and print it out

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to read from a user input and count the punctuation from the sentence and print it out. Can anyone please guide me what is the correct way of doing it. My code doesn't work correctly.

Thank you

```
int digit = 0, letter = 0, punc = 0;
    char c;

for (int a = 0; a<sentence.length(); a++){
        c=sentence.charAt(a);


        if(Character.isLetter(c))
            letter++;

        if(Character.isDigit(c))
            digit++;

        if(sentence.contains("[\\p{Punct}]")){
            punc++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `String#contains` don't take a regex

Comment: `String.contains` does not use regular expressions. Your code looks for the exact string `[\\p{Punct}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're treating all non-letters, non-digits and non-whitespace as punctuation, then this might work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int digit = 0, letter = 0, punc = 0;
        char c;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);      
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence below \n\n");
        String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();

        for (int a = 0; a < sentence.length(); a++) {
            c = sentence.charAt(a);

            if (Character.isLetter(c))
                letter++;

            if (Character.isDigit(c))
                digit++;

            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c) && !Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                punc++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Letters: " + letter);
        System.out.println("Numbers: " + digit);
        System.out.println("Punctuation: " + punc);
}
```

Produces output:

```
Letters: 10
Numbers: 1
Punctuation: 1
```

Comment: My output is still show 0  when i run System.out.println(punc); Am i doing wrong on somewhere ?

Comment: @Who without seeing your code it's hard to tell. I've edited my answer to show a more complete solution. Does that help?

Comment: Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a sentence below \n\n"); 

I am prompting the user to enter any sentence they want, the example you provide was having a fix input. When i run System.out.println("Punctuation: " + punc); 
The output was still 0.
Appreciate for your help, buddy.

Comment: I've amended my answer again to include the code you're using to accept input. I can only think that either you're not reading the string in correctly, or perhaps you're forgetting to put some punctuation in ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since `String#contains` does not use regex, you need to use another method to count the punctuations.

Use `Pattern` and `Matcher`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Punct}]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Hi, I'm testing the Regex Expression !");

while (m.find()) {
    punc++;
}

System.out.println(punc); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the command:

```
if(sentence.contains("[\\p{Punct}]")){
    punc++;
}
```

which means 'if the sentence contains punctuation, then add 1 to the punctuation counter' once for each character. Therefore, if the sentence contains any punctuation at all, the result will be the length of the sentence, not the number of punctuation characters.

Maybe use

```
if (Pattern.matches("\\p{Punct}", chr)) {
   punc++;
}
```

Where `chr` is a String containing the current character.

That way, you are checking individual characters each time instead of the whole sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify your code too much, then you can use

```
int digit = 0, letter = 0, punc = 0;
char c;
String sentence = "abc, (kl{}";

for (int a = 0; a<sentence.length(); a++){
    c=sentence.charAt(a);

    if(Character.isLetter(c))
        letter++;

    if(Character.isDigit(c))
        digit++;

    if(("" + c).matches("[\\p{Punct}]")){
        punc++;
    }    
 }
System.out.println(punc);
}
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/HbtTtA)**

Not exactly the best way though